# Javascript press key on input class

Tags: javascript

I am trying to press a key on an input on my page using javascript.

Needs to be as a one line of code like:

```
javascript:oninputmyInput.pressKeynum1();
```

can this be done?

Comment: You mean you want to generate an event letting the browser think a key was pressed ?

Comment: No I want to simulate a keypress

Comment: Now I'm confused as I don't see the difference...

Comment: Are you expecting the key pressed to add a character to the input? You can simulate the event, but it will not actually type the character in the box.

Comment: Yes I want to add a character to an input...so it cannot be done?

Comment: with `jquery` you can trigger `keypress` manually

Comment: can jquery be adding like: javascript:$('#something').trigger(); ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Reference for Answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/596481/simulate-javascript-key-events)

If you are ok to use jQuery [Workig JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6Djsb/):

```
   // jQuery plugin. Called on a jQuery object, not directly.
jQuery.fn.simulateKeyPress = function(character) {
  // Internally calls jQuery.event.trigger
  // with arguments (Event, data, elem). That last arguments is very important!
  jQuery(this).trigger({ type: 'keypress', which: character.charCodeAt(0) });
};

jQuery(document).ready( function($) {
  // Bind event handler
  $( 'body' ).keypress( function(e) {
    alert( String.fromCharCode( e.which ) );
    console.log(e);
  });
  // Simulate the key press
  $( 'body' ).simulateKeyPress('x');
});
```

A non-jquery version that works in both webkit and gecko:

```
var keyboardEvent = document.createEvent("KeyboardEvent");
var initMethod = typeof keyboardEvent.initKeyboardEvent !== 'undefined' ? "initKeyboardEvent" : "initKeyEvent";


keyboardEvent[initMethod](
                   "keydown", // event type : keydown, keyup, keypress
                    true, // bubbles
                    true, // cancelable
                    window, // viewArg: should be window
                    false, // ctrlKeyArg
                    false, // altKeyArg
                    false, // shiftKeyArg
                    false, // metaKeyArg
                    40, // keyCodeArg : unsigned long the virtual key code, else 0
                    0 // charCodeArgs : unsigned long the Unicode character associated with the depressed key, else 0
);
document.dispatchEvent(keyboardEvent);
```

Answer (score 1):

Based on comments am posting this even `jquery` is not tagged

```
// dummy event listener
$("input").keydown(function() { return true; });

var keyEvent = jQuery.Event("keydown");
keyEvent.keyCode = 13;
$("input").trigger(keyEvent);
```

with this you manually trigger `keydown` event and this is for `enter` event